# When moving from local machine to server, Crystal requires further information to log on to database

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, logging

I know this has been posted before by other users and I have tried looking at all the answers already answered and tried everything but nothing seems to be working. So here i am posting the question again with my code....Please help me out...This works fine on the local machine and the crystal report is generated but when I put it on the server it asks for further information for the database like server name, UserName, Password...Tried everything but no use....Please help...

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
    using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.IO;

    public partial class ImageCrystal : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


     //var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
     //    connectionInfo.ServerName = "157.182.x.xxx";
     //    connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "xxxx";
     //    connectionInfo.Password = "xxxx";
     //    connectionInfo.UserID = "xxxx";
     //    connectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL;
     //    connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;

    //    for (int i = 0; i < CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo.Count; i++)
    //{
    //    CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo[i].ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
    //}

    // trying to load an image
    ReportDocument rptTest1 = new ReportDocument();
    rptTest1.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Image.rpt"));
    rptTest1.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(rptTest.ImageTable(Server.MapPath("~/Brochures/Test3.jpg")));

    ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions;

    ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition;
    ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition1;
    ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
    ParameterValues crParameterValues1 = new ParameterValues();
    ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox1.Text;
    crParameterFieldDefinitions = rptTest1.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
    crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["CountyofArea"];
    crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

    crParameterValues.Clear();
    crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
    crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

    crParameterDiscreteValue1.Value = TextBox2.Text;
    crParameterFieldDefinitions = rptTest1.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
    crParameterFieldDefinition1 = crParameterFieldDefinitions["Area"];
    crParameterValues1 = crParameterFieldDefinition1.CurrentValues;

    crParameterValues1.Clear();
    crParameterValues1.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue1);
    crParameterFieldDefinition1.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues1);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptTest1;


           // Exporting it as a PDf
              try
    {
        ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
        DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
        PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
        CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = Server.MapPath("~/Brochures/XMLReport.pdf");
        CrExportOptions = rptTest1.ExportOptions;
        {
            CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
            CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
            CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
            CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
        }
        rptTest1.Export();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

public class rptTest
{
    public static DataTable ImageTable(string ImageFile)
    {
        Image ds = new Image();
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;
        data.TableName = "Images";
        data.Columns.Add("Image", System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"));
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(ImageFile, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        row = data.NewRow();
        row[0] = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(br.BaseStream.Length));
        data.Rows.Add(row);
        br = null;
        fs.Close();
        fs = null;
     //  ds.Tables[0].Merge(data);
        return data;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is it the only place in your application where you connect to the database ? Is the connection to the database works in other parts of your application ?

Comment: Yes it works fine in other places where I try to connect to the database. I mean in places other than crystal reports...

Comment: Plzzzz someone help me out....atleast some ideas...I have tried everything but nothing seems to work....

Comment: Maybe give more details about what you tried. The code you provided is not explicit apart from the connection code that is commented out. And what line of code gives the error ? the code does many things that could require credentials.

Comment: @Matthieu: Sorry for a late response...was out of town....I have tried using that code that is commented out and then I have even tried to give the username and password in the code( simila to the commented out code)....but nothing that I have done in the code works...dont know if there is anything external that needs to be set or done....

Comment: I guess the code that is loading the image report and setting the data source could be the problem...I have tried putting break points and checking where it gives an error...but it breaks out of the program and asks me for the database logon details at the line rptTest1.Export....SO not sure why it is breaking up....Please help..

Comment: Try without the empty catch-exception, to see if you have more details on the error. You should avoid empty chatches, and at least rethrow the exception.

Comment: I just tried rethrowing the exception and it says database Login failed...that is the error that it is displaying....so not sure...how to handle it...any ideas...plzzz

Comment: Can anyone please write something....give sme ideas plzzzzz.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,this code should work

```
TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos()
TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
connectionInfo.ServerName = "157.182.x.xxx";
connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "xxxx";
connectionInfo.Password = "xxxx";
connectionInfo.UserID = "xxxx";
connectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL;
for (int i = 0; i < CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo.Count; i++)
  {
      CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo[i].ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
  }
```

Comment: Helped me today, Thanks.